# dyld fatal error when running XCUITest

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots

I get a dyld fatal error as xcode attempts to initiate the UI test suite.

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9A03F81B-1A93-4F0E-88B0-56C0748D1D43/ExampleUITests-Runner.app/XCTRunner
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9A03F81B-1A93-4F0E-88B0-56D0748D1D43/ExampleUITests-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9A03F81B-1A93-4F0E-88B0-56D0748D1D43/ExampleUITests-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'
```

So I'm running this on a Mac Mini which is a designated testing workstation.  I have the same identical project on my macbook and it runs fine.  I tried deleting my project and re-cloning it and it still goes through the same issue.

Any ideas on what the issue may be?

On a side note, I had this issue before.  My solution was doing a re-format since re-installing Xcode and recloning my project from github did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was an error regarding my certificates and this issue was resolved by revoking my certificates and resetting all of them.

Then I had to remove the problem apps from my device from Window > Devices and that allowed me to run my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to suggest that Xcode is not able to locate XCTest.framework on your mac mini.Did you try adding `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` to Framework Search Path of your UI Test Target.
You can also test adding XCTest.framework as a Build Phases Dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I tried that already and it had no effect.  I did manage to fix it though and the problem ended up being my keychain access.  I revoked everything and reset all my keychains and that took care of the error.  Then I had to remove the problem apps from my device from Window > Devices and that allowed me to run my tests.